# iOS screenshot submission. Simulator screenshot have simulation name. Does it matter?

Tags: ios, screenshot, review

I have a screenshot of an iOS taken from the simulator. I am not a graphic designer and not sure so I just upload the whole screenshot with background and upload to the App Store. I only upload 6.5 inch and 12.9 inch screenshot and it uploads fine. I checked carefully with the upload image size.

One thing I am concerning is the ability to pass the review.

[image]

Comment: Even if it doesn't pass review, I'm sure the worst that will happen is they will tell you to crop it out. I can't see it being a huge deal.

Comment: Why does your screenshot show the simulator name? That's not the proper way to take screenshots in the simulator.

Comment: Yeah. No worries about review. It's not like a one-shot type deal. You have the opportunity to make corrections and resubmit.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not a simulator screen shot. It is a Mac screen shot of the simulator app, and it is wrong. To make a simulator screen shot, run the app in the simulator and press command-S. The screen shot of the simulator screen, at the correct size, is saved by the simulator to the desktop.